# How to uninstall .NET Framework 4.8 in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have downloaded the .Net Framework 4.8 from 'https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net48' and installed it sucessfully.

But it doesn't appear in Visual Studio in the target framework list, so I installed .Net Framework 4.8 again, but encountered a message

> .NET Framework 4.8 or a later update is already installed on this computer

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: As your question stands right now it is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. That being said I'll attempt to help you out anyways. What Visual Studio version are you using (2017 or 2019?)

Comment: @MindSwipe using vs2017

Comment: @MindSwipe as a important point, i can't  find .Net4.8 in  "Add or remove programs" list,but vs installer tell me  the message ".NET Framework 4.8 or a later update is already installed on this computer.",    it seems wired, maybe i install  exception at first.

Answer (score 2):

To make .NET 4.8 show up in your Visual Studio, you need to install the [.NET Framework 4.8 Developer Pack](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2088517)

Comment: @mac_s  thank you for you help, i use the wrong way to download net4.8 runtime.

Comment: Well, actually, this answer has NOT resolve the original question of how to uninstall .net framework 4.8 completely? I seem to read somewhere that 4.8 is in place update, so you can't go back once it is installed, is this true? if it is, then it is a terrible decision by Microsoft

Comment: For the record, this helped me completely, since I was only trying to uninstall it to *fix* it (Windows claimed it was installed, but VS claimed it *wasn't* installed) - and just installing this developer pack install fixed the issues with VS without having to uninstall anything. Thanks!